# Jquery function call on click event function

Tags: jquery, function, key-bindings

JQuery problem today here is the code: *hope it makes sense*

```
$(function() {
    var distence = 0;
    $('.right').click(function() {
        distence -= 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distence + '%)')
        console.log(distence);
    });
    $('.left').click(function() {
        distence += 100;
        $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distence + '%);')
        console.log(distence);
    });


$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault()
    keyClick();
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    keyClick();
  }
});
    });
```

I am aiming to run the function

```
$('.right').click(function() {
    distence -= 100;
    $('#container').css('transform', 'translateX(' + distence + '%)')
    console.log(distence);
});
```

Every time I click enter or space key but I'm having trouble making it run that function, as you can see I have

```
keyClick();
```

once they click enter or space but I don't know how to call the function I am aiming for, if anyone could help me out that would be great thank you.

Comment: `keyClick()` function doesn't exists

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I know I can't think how to name my aiming function that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not defined a `function keyClick()`, or forgot to post it. But, what you want can be done also as:

```
if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.right').trigger('click');
  }
```

Perhaps this will help you .

Now if you want to use it as a function, then you should do something like:

```
function keyClick()
{
$('.right').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) like

`$('.right').trigger('click')` to trigger the anonymous click event handler. `$('.right').click()` will also do the trick (*shortcut for `.trigger( "click" )`*)